# Writing test code for wrapper class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I created a controller which looks like this

```
public with sharing class EventRegistrationController {

    // A CONTROLLER FUNCTION
    // FUNCTION RETURNS A LIST OF cSession
     public List<cSession> getSessions() {

          //DO STUFF

     }

   //A PUBLIC CLASS WITHIN CONTROLLER
   @TestVisible public class cSession 
    {
        public Session__c con {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        //This is the contructor method. 
        public cSession(Session__c c) {

            con = c;
            selected = false;
        }
    }
 }
```

I need to write a test code for the controller, how can I create a list of `cSession` and call `getSession` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new cSession in the following way:

```
EventRegistrationController.cSession cSession = new EventRegistrationController.cSession(c);
```

You can call the getSessions method using:

```
EventRegistrationController controller = new EventRegistrationController();
List<EventRegistrationController.cSession> controller.getSessions();
```